# HappyMapper namespace prefix error

Tags: ruby, xml, xml-namespaces

I have the following XML doc, and would like to convert the xml to object using happymapper.

```
<objects>
<item>
<title>book1</title>
<link>http://asdf.com</link>
<pubDate>march 1 2009</pubDate>
<description>testtesttest</description>
<media:thumbnail url='http://url.com' />
</item>
<item>
<title>book2</title>
<link>http://dffdfdf.com</link>
<pubDate>march 3 2009</pubDate>
<description>testtesttest</description>
<media:thumbnail url='http://url.com' />
</item>
</objects>

#HappyMapper object
class Item
 include HappyMapper
 namespace 'http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/'
 element :title, String
 element :link, String
 element :pubDate, String
 element :description, String
 element :media_thumbnail, String, :tag=>'media:thumbnail', :attributes=>{:url=>String}
end

items=Item.parse(xml_document)
items.each do |i|
 puts i.title
 puts i.media_thumbnail.url
end
```

Error: Namespace prefix media on thumbnail is not defined at :11.

Error: Namespace prefix media on thumbnail is not defined at :22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check that your XML document has a namespace definition for prefix `media`. Element `<media:thumbnail>` or one of its ancestors should have a namespace definition that looks like `xmlns:media="http://some.uri"`. If there is no namespace-uri to prefix mapping, then your XML is not (namespace) well-formed which causes the parsing to fail.
2. Check that you have defined the correct namespace for the `thumbnail` element in the HappyMapper code.

Comment: Thanks I needed to add the ns to my xml doc. but it worked without having to add ns to happymapper object.